# python importing file on virtual environment

Tags: python, python-venv, c9.io

I am writing a web app using python3, venv and c9.io PAAS. I have the following structure of my code:

```
batch_runner.py
logic/
    __init__.py
    parsers/
        __init__.py
        time_parser.py
        abstract_parser.py
```

here `batch_runner` imports `abstract_parser`, which, in it turn, import from time_parser. everything was installed and runs with venv activated.

To be specific, `batch_runner.py` contains:

```
from logic.parsers import abstract
from sys import argv

url = argv[1]
a = abstract(url)
```

`logic/__init__.py` is empty. `logic/parsers/__init__.py` contains:

```
from abstract_parser import abstract
from time_parser import _timeInfo
```

If I go to `logic` and run `python abstract_parser.py` directly, everything works as expected. However, if I go one level up, and run `python batch_runner.py`, it is able to import `abstract_parser`, but it can't find `time_parser` which is called from `abstract_parser`, throwing `ImportError: No module named 'abstract'`

Comment: Please add what file imports what, and the exact import statements you're using. Are you using `from logic import abstract_parser`? How are you trying to import `time_parser`? What does the `__init__.py` file contain?

Comment: thanks. Added all the information on importing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do read about importing from the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on modules.

In this case, one possible solution is to use relative imports inside your package:

That is, in `logic/parsers/__init__.py`, use:

```
from .abstract_parser import abstract
from .time_parser import _timeInfo
```

and in `abstract_parser.py`:

```
from .time_parser import _timeInfo
```

This should let `parsers/__init__.py` find the `abstract_parser` module and the `time_parser` module.

The python import system has a surprising number of traps that you can fall into. [This blog post](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) by Nick Coghlan describes many of them, and I personally consider it a must-read if you're planning to develop a package.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
from abstract_parser import abstract
```

To

```
from logic.parsers.abstract_parser import abstract
```

Comment: If you're using this solution, you can leave `parsers/__init__.py` empty, and use `from logic.parsers import abstract_parser as ap` followed by `ap.abstract( ... )` when you call, for instance. This is particularly useful when there are plenty of names under abstract_parser that you need to import.